# Dispute Failed VLQ audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Today I failed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19179307) in the low quality queue that I though looked OK because it explained what needed to be done and linked to (possible) helpful documentation.

The reason for this failure was that it was spam.

Did I make a mistake or did another bad audit slip in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you probably should have noticed is that the OP was affiliated with the website they link to *and* that it is a self-answer.

It is a known spam seed setup: ask a (simple) innocent question, answer with spam.

The problem here is that the particular OP posted a bunch of those, all making it very suspicious but the remaining rest of their posts look legit. I've casted a total of 4 helpful spam flags on various post from that same OP. The user's posts did get picked up by the [Smoke Detector](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=&username=Amplience+Support&why=&site=1&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search).

In this case I think you made a mistake, yes. While the post seems legit there were enough signals in the review that should have made you visit the Q/A pair and the OP's profile to verify what you're dealing with.

Comment: Thanks for this very clear explenation of what i did wrong.